# Google sign-in won't redirect

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have the following code in my index.jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>   

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="123lettersandnumbers123.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<link href="<s:url value="/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<s:url value="/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<s:url value="/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="<s:url value="/assets/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.js"/>"></script>
<script src="<s:url value="/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"/>"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 function onSignIn(googleUser) {
      var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
      console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
      console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
      console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
      console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
    }
 </script> 

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">



<title>My test</title>
</head>
<body>
This is the index
<br>
<br>

<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" ></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my Google console configuration:

- Javascript origin : http://localhost:8080
- Authorized redirect URIs : http://localhost:8080/mytest/success.jsp

When I press the "sign in" button the google account popup appears and, upon successful authentication, there is no redirection, it just stays in index.jsp. The only thing that changes is the button caption (to "signed in"). What am I doing wrong?.